# C# SmtpClient.Send() is slow because of BCC

Tags: c#, performance, smtpclient, bcc

I'm using "System.Net.Mail" for send email on our Intranet system in C#

The Send() method was very slow and I did not understand why.

After debugging, I've remove the BCC call : (MM is a MailMessage() and Item, a string email address) :

```
MM.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(Item));
```

Before I comment this line, an email was taking about 30 or 40 seconds. Now, it's about 2 seconds. Why?

Is there an explication about this? I can add "To" and "CC" with no problem of performance. But not "BCC".

Comment: Does the delay happen on the send or on Bcc.Add?

Comment: Are you sure it's .NET and not your mail server?

Comment: How many BCC are you adding?

Comment: How many BCC addresses are you sending to? Each one is a separate send...

Comment: CodeCaster has the intuition - it may be your mail server not handling BCC well, esp. if the list is huge. Peek at this - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21089346

Comment: I'm adding 4 emails in BCC and during the debug, the delay is on the "Send()" method line. But, with the same SMTP server, on outlook, the same email and recipients does not take time.

Comment: Might be helpful to Fiddle the .NET app vs Outlook...

Comment: Also try different SMTP server (maybe gmail?)

Comment: I can't use an external SMTP server. I'm not allowed.

Comment: Ok, I've try with the smtp server "auth.smtp.1and1.fr" and it's very fast with Bcc recipients. But, why it's slow in an App .Net and fast in Outlook? I don't know...

Comment: Did you try to add all email addresses at once? `xxx.Bcc.Add("r1@huhu.de,r2@huhu.de,r3@huhu.de");`

Comment: It's the same : too long

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem and this drove me crazy trying to figure out what made some emails slow and others quick.

The first email sent after creating SmtpClient takes 5 seconds.  After that, reusing the same SmtpClient, it's about 0.4 seconds if done within 60 seconds of the previous one.  After that I think it releases it's connection to the pool.

However adding a CC that is a duplicate of the To address will always add an additional 5 seconds. Adding a duplicate CC twice will add 10 seconds.

I didn't check, but I assume the same would be true if duplicates are in the "TO" or "BCC" lists.

Here's the code to remove duplicates:

```
// check and remove duplicates
for (int x = 0; x < message.To.Count; x++)
{
    for (int y = message.To.Count - 1; y > x; y--)
    {
        if (message.To[y].Address == message.To[x].Address)
            message.To.RemoveAt(y);
    }
    for (int y = message.CC.Count - 1; y >= 0; y--)
    {
        if (message.CC[y].Address == message.To[x].Address)
            message.CC.RemoveAt(y);
    }
    for (int y = message.Bcc.Count - 1; y >= 0; y--)
    {
        if (message.Bcc[y].Address == message.To[x].Address)
            message.Bcc.RemoveAt(y);
    }
}
for (int x = 0; x < message.CC.Count; x++)
{
    for (int y = message.CC.Count - 1; y > x; y--)
    {
        if (message.CC[y].Address == message.CC[x].Address)
            message.CC.RemoveAt(y);
    }
    for (int y = message.Bcc.Count - 1; y >= 0; y--)
    {
        if (message.Bcc[y].Address == message.CC[x].Address)
            message.Bcc.RemoveAt(y);
    }
}
for (int x = 0; x < message.Bcc.Count; x++)
{
    for (int y = message.Bcc.Count - 1; y > x; y--)
    {
        if (message.Bcc[y].Address == message.Bcc[x].Address)
            message.Bcc.RemoveAt(y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. We ran into this. Very strange behaviour. I assume it is a bug.